# Multiple websites on same machine

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have a couple of websites hosted on the same machine, in order to be able to access them from their domain names without any sub-directories in the url I suppose I need to use virtual hosts. Currently I've added 2 virtual hosts - one for localhost and one for a live domain

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/ProjectA/Public"
    ServerName domain.com
    ErrorLog "logs/domain.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/domain.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

The folder structure in under **htodcs** is the following

```
htdocs/ProjectA/Public
htdocs/ProjectB/Public
```

The problem is that when I try to access `http://localhost` I get the `domain.com`home page but the address in the browser is `http://localhost`.

How do I need to set up the virtual hosts so that I can access both projects + access the root of localhost?

Comment: The configuration seems okay and we have a similar configuration working except that we have <VirtualHost *:80> directives.

Comment: @ArnaudKleinveld I don't believe that adding a default port explicitly would be causing this but I will try adding it anyway.

Comment: Well, what do you know, it suddenly started working without me changing anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectA\Public\"
ServerName projecta.domain.com
</VirtualHost>    
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectB\Public\"
ServerName projectb.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

You will also need to point projects.domain.com and projects.domain.com to the IP address in DNS or the hosts file.

Comment: they are under different domains. Also what part in this does the hosts file play when the requests are not coming from the host itself?

Comment: So changethe server names accordingly. The clients need to be able to resolve the host names to IP addresses

Comment: I'm sorry I don't seem to understand. Can you explain to me what is the problem with the way I've currently set it up, maybe then it will be clear to me. I have set correct values for `ServerName` in the vhosts configuration file if that is what you're suggesting